# How do I click a div with a specific text using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: javascript, html, testing, selenium

I am using Selenium Webdriver to test a program in JavaScript.

I want to click on an element that I get after I input some data in a search box. The problem is that, as I don't create that object, I can not give it an id in and refer to it while I'm testing.

Is there a way to refer to a tag containing a specific text?

```
  it('Should select a song', function(done) {
  client
    .setValue('#email', 'partygoer@email.com')
    .setValue('#query', 'superstition')
    .click('#search')
    .waitFor('.cover', 5000)
    .click('Here I have to click on the element with the specific text')
    .click('#submit')
    .waitFor('#thank-you')
    .getText('#thank-you', function(err, text) {
      expect(text).to.include('hello partygoer@email.com, your song id is')
    })
    .call(done);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to find the element using jquery then use the [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

```
$('tagname[attribute]:contains("specific text")');

$('div:contains("searchterm")');
```

Or

```
$('div#test').filter(function(){ return $(this).text();});
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: I am not using jQuery though, I tried anyway to reach that element as you've suggested, but it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it by selecting the text of the link that I want to click on, with the following syntax: to click this TextHere I can .click('link=TextHere') and it will select that element..